# Salesforce CI/CD, from Change Set to SFDX with GitLab

Tags: salesforcedx, jwt, continuous-integration, cicd, plugin-bug

I would like to ask about CI/CD in SFDC.

Currently my team is doing this:

1. Developing in a sandbox (first sandbox)
2. Testing (UAT) in another sandbox (second sandbox)
3. Deploying our custom codes or settings to Production using
   changesets(Production)

Now with GitLab ready, we would like to bring it in so that we can have version control. How can we start?

My idea is to connect the GitLab repo to the sandbox first. But I do not really know how to do that (pushing codes from GitLab to sandbox).

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best place to start is [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/). Here are some cool stuff on it which can explore:-

1. [Build an Automated CI/CD Pipeline with GitLab](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/automate-cicd-with-gitlab)
2. [Continuous Integration Using Salesforce DX](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sfdx_travis_ci)
3. [GitLab + Salesforce: DevOps Made Easy](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/05/gitlab-salesforce-devops-made-easy.html)
4. [Simplify Your Development Process with Continuous Integration](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/move-to-a-continuous-integration-development)
5. [Accelerate DevOps With Gitlab and salesforce - Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tylPp9QlLu4)

Comment: Hi Sanket, I have tried following the first trailhead module "Build an Automated CI/CD Pipeline with GitLab" and it works. My question now is how can I manage all the metadata in my org in a way that every developer can integrate their codes? People include all metadata in their DX project folder or only the metadata they want to modify in their project [Like the Dreamhouse project in the Trailhead example]?

Comment: @ZhuangPaulus you can have a look to sfdx-hardis (CLI + VsCode extension), it's not very documented yet but it's working and provides an abstraction UI layer that allows collaborators to Create a scratch org and generate a merge request without having to know Git of SFDX commands :) https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NicolasVuillamy.vscode-sfdx-hardis